# Collection views cannot get text from label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created two collection views in one view controller. For unknown reason I cannot get text from UILabel for second collection view.

I created two custom cells and put labels in storyboard.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainNumbers: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalNumbers: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mainNumbers.delegate = self
        mainNumbers.dataSource = self

        horizontalNumbers.delegate = self
        horizontalNumbers.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == mainNumbers {
           return 81
        } else {
           return 5
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == mainNumbers {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
            cell.label.text = "f"
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! CellSecond
            cell.cellSecond.text = "fds"
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            return cell
        }



    }

}
```

For second collection view label nothing are displayed. I cannot get the reason why.

```
class MainCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}

class CellSecond: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cellSecond: UILabel!
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to check `cellSecond` is connected with outlet, Use proper naming convetion for `collectionView` like change first collectionView name and `cellForItemAt` only require `if..else`

Comment: I checked everything and made the changes you wrote, but anyway no text is displaying for second collection view.

Comment: cell's background color display properly? and can you show your output?

Comment: Yes. I added the screenshot to my question.

Comment: Try to disconnect outlet for `cellSecond` and connect it again and make sure has same properties like first collectionView's `label`

Comment: Can you share CellSecond class code?

Comment: I added CellSecond class code.

Comment: I tried to disconnet and connect, but it didn't help. It has the same property like first collectionView label.

Comment: I will suggest to go for 1 collectionView and two cells in it, but if you want like this then you should give `tag` to collectionView. Give `mainNumber.tag = 1` and other `2`. The in `cellForRowAt`, check  `if collectionView.tag == 1 { }  else { }`

Comment: I tried with tags, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: there's no need to create two different classes. Create just one like this:

```swift
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
let label: UILabel = {
       let lab = UILabel()
        lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lab.contentMode =  .scaleAspectFit
        lab.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        lab.clipsToBounds = true
        lab.numberOfLines = 3
        
        return lab
    }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            
            contentView.addSubview(label)

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
   }
}
```

Now register both cells as you did but assigning to the both of them `MyCollectionViewCell` and call `cell.label.text = "whateverYouWant"`.